# How Do I Add Calculated Rows Together To Form A Grand Total

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created an invoice table that provides rows from the database table where order ID in the database is equal to a value passed in the URL.  The table works perfectly.  Here is the code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID LIMIT 10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {   
$quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];   
$description = $row['NAME'];   
$unitprice = $row['PRICE'];   
$lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY']; 

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 650px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>'; 
$tbl = '';

// foreach item in your array... $tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($quantity,0).'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 350px; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$description.'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($unitprice,2).'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;" align="right" ><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($lineprice,2).'</p></td>
    </tr> ';
```

This code loops all the rows within the order. It shows:

```
Quantity     | Product Name     | Price     | Line Total
1            | Gold Frame       | £10.00    | £10.00
3            | Silver Frame     | £5.00     | £15.00
```

So my question.  How do I get the total of the line total, so for the above example I'm wanting GRAND TOTAL to equal £25.00.

I understand there will be a GROUP BY ID but I'm not sure how to add the multiple values quantity * price for each row together.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you're looking for an SQL-only solution? because that PHP loop is well capable of calculating this on its own...

Comment: p.s. your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce new variable at the beginning prior to the loop and increment her value for $lineprice in each loop iteration.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_sale_basket WHERE ORDER_ID=$ID LIMIT 10");

$total=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {   
$quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];   
$description = $row['NAME'];   
$unitprice = $row['PRICE'];   
$lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY']; 
$total=$total+$lineprice;

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 650px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>'; 
$tbl = '';

// foreach item in your array... $tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px; text-align: left; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($quantity,0).'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 350px; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.$description.'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;"><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($unitprice,2).'</p></td>
        <td style="width: 125px; text-align:right; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #808080;" align="right" ><p style="color:#808080;">'.number_format($lineprice,2).'</p></td>
    </tr> ';
```

Once you done with the loop add `<tr><td>` and print total.

Answer (score 3):

Just add it up while you loop over your results:

```
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {   
  $quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];   
  $description = $row['NAME'];   
  $unitprice = $row['PRICE'];   
  $lineprice = $row['PRICE']*$row['QUANTITY'];
  $total += $lineprice;
}

echo $total;
```